# Windows application - RDLC report - reportviewer 2015 - fonts showing blurry?

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2015, c++-cli, rdlc, reportviewer

Iam using VS2015. With my Windows Application, I have RDLC Report Viewed by ReportViewer 2015. Simply It's good in many system. But the fonts showing blurry with report Viewer only in one of my user system. So how to avoid this problem?

I try to setup Additional Manifest file for DPI_Aware, but no changes. I don't Know the mistakes...? Any guidances will be helpfuls
my Codes

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<assembly manifestVersion="1.0" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" xmlns:asmv3="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
<asmv3:application  xmlns:asmv3="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3" >
  <asmv3:windowsSettings xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SMI/2005/WindowsSettings">
    <dpiAware>true</dpiAware>
  </asmv3:windowsSettings>
</asmv3:application>
</assembly>
```

Thanks For the helps